django-cacheops error: Unknown Redis command called from Lua script
Using these versions I'm trying to cache data in Django with cacheops
Python = 3.12.4
Redis = 7.0.4
Django = 5.0.7
django-cacheops = 7.0.2

but the response returns the following error:
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Error running script (call to f_0605214935a9ffcd4b9e5779300302540ff08da4): @user_script:36: @user_script: 36: Unknown Redis command called from Lua script

What could be the reason?
Sample Code:

I can't see the sample code, please make sure to format it accordingly.
